# Find the area bounded by the curves $y=e^x$, $y=xe^x$, and $x=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Find the area bounded by the curves $y=e^x$, $y=xe^x$, and $x=0$

I know how to solve the integral for this, but I'm getting hung up trying to find the points of intersection for the two equations.

So I did what I normally do for these problems:

$$e^x = xe^x$$

I then did this (and this is where I get lost):

$$ln(e^x) = ln(xe^x)$$

So I know for the left side its just $x$ but what does the right side simplify to?  Or, did I do this wrong?

Comment: x = x^2....what does this tell you about $x$ OP????

Comment: Oh my... I now see the simplicity in this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check two cases.

First let $e^x \neq 0$. This implies $x \neq 1$. Divide both sides by $e^x$ and you'll get $x=1$. A contradiction.

Now check the case when $e^x = 0$. This case provide one solution, that's $x=1$

Also you can continue where you've stopped:

$$\ln e^x = \ln xe^x$$
$$x = \ln e^x + \ln x$$
$$x = x + \ln x$$
$$\ln x = 0 \implies x=1$$

Comment: I'm so embarrassed, I see the simplicity in this now.  Thank you.

Comment: I guess I'm so used to taking the natural log by rote when its algebra involving $e^x$ that I didn't look at it any other way.

Comment: @inquisitor That's the reason we are here, to help each other. Don't feel embarrasses, as once my teacher said: "It's not embarrassing if you don't know something, it's embarrassing if you don't want to learn that".

Comment: @inquisitor There are lot of different ways to go here, but the one I've posted is probably the easiest. Actually we can continue where you've stopped. 

$$\ln e^x = \ln xe^x$$
$$x = \ln e^x + \ln x$$
$$x = x + \ln x$$
$$\ln x = 0 \implies x=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Do this $(x-1)e^x=0$ , Then either of them should be zero . Now $e^x \ne0$ for any value of $x$ hence $x=1$ . Now use the limits $x=0$ to $x=1$ for the integration

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int (e^x - xe^x )dx = \int e^x(1-x)dx =  \int (1-x) de^x = (1-x)e^x -\int e^x d(1-x) = (1-x)e^x + \int e^x dx = (1-x)e^x + e^x = e^x(2-x) = F(x)$$

Now, $F(1) - F(0) = e - 2 $